# Time complexity for partitioning a set and sorting the partition's subsets

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

Suppose I have a function which partitions set `S`, `|S|=n`, into `S/subsetSize` subsets of size `subsetSize` and sorts each subset:

```
partitionAndSort(Set s, int subsetSize) {
   List partition = partitionList(s);
   for(Set subset: partition) {
      sort(subset);
   }
}
```

What's the running time of the function?

`partition` clearly takes `O(n)` because we go through the elements of the set one by one. `subsetSize` is considered to be a constant, hence an individual sort takes `O(subsetSize*log(subsetSize))=O(1)`, and there are `O(n/subsetSize)=O(n)` sorting calls. Does the overall sorting take `O(n)`? Does that give a running time of `O(n)` for the function?

Comment: Can you tell why you're asking? Are you surprised by the result? Or do you just want confirmation by someone else? Or something else?

Comment: It's just getting overall O(n) when there's sorting doesn't feel comfortable. I would like a confirmation by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your function only needs O(n). Bear in mind, though, that it's *not* sorting the given set. Only the subsets. Hence there's no conflict with the n log n lower bound for (comparison-based) sorting of a set of n values, as you're not doing that.